# Python testing / TeamCity integration / sane package management

Tags: python, windows, version-control, teamcity, package-managers

My colleagues and I are currently taking baby steps to automate the testing of an embryonic python codebase, but we've run into some problems regarding environment setup & package management.  Any help is appreciated, as we've not done this before with Python (and it looks [a bit... fractured](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/14/a-few-corrections-to-on-packaging/)).

**Requirements:**

- Tests are runnable via a script ([Nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) looks quite good)
- It runs on windows machines
- It is runnable via [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as well as standard developer machines.  Good TeamCity reporting / integration would be a bonus.
- We should be able to invoke the scripts and get correct, repeatable results on multiple machines.
- All dependencies / package requirements are met in a simple, repeatable fashion (we do this with our main codebase using ruby & bundler and are struggling to repeat the trick with python).  If people have to go about manually installing eggs / using easy_install etc. it's going to be hellish.  You should just be able to invoke a script that says "please make sure these dependencies are accounted for, then run our tests".

Ideally the workflow should work like this (ignoring how we install/get python for the moment):

- Windows machine syncs up to our SCM
- Machine runs a script to ensure that all python dependencies (Shapely etc.) are accounted for
- Machine is able to invoke a script that runs nose or some other test runner
- The script returns a value to indicate whether the build failed

**Bonus points question**:

We are willing to install python on each dev machine / build agent rather than checking it in to source control, though it would be nice if we could just check it in and forget about it.  Our best bet on this front thus far is just to check the python install directory into SCM along with the pythonxx.dll found in Windows/System32, but I'm not sure if this is a flawed approach.

We've spotted [Movable Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/) and [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/).  Any idea what the best approach is?  Like I said, we are willing to just bite the bullet and install python on each machine using an .msi if this is not viable.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of anything better, we prodded at the problem via trial and error.  At the moment, our codebase is tiny, so there may be flaws in this approach that have yet to be exposed, but we're going with it for the moment.

In the end, we:

- Added [PortablePython](http://www.portablepython.com/) 2.7 to SCM.  This just-works(tm).
- Added [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to SCM
- Created a windows .bat file that invokes curl and pulls down and installs python setup tools.  We then install pip via setup tools (meta packaging ahoy).  Pip is then run against a requirements file.  The pip requirements file contains nose (a python test runner) and teamcity-nose (TeamCity CI integration for nose) amongst other things.

We then invoke the test runner which automagically hoovered up our tests without any hassle.  Not bad!

Also going to check out [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) in future.

**Edit** (N years into the future):

Pip comes as standard in Python 2.7.9 and beyond. Easiest way to do things these days (imo) is something like:

1. use pip out of the box
2. install virtualenv
3. create a virtualenv for the project & activate it
4. install dependencies using pip (occasionally have to fall back to easy_install, unfortunately)
5. disco.

Also, don't use portable python unless you really need it. Really wish we'd not settled for that.